# Missing package product,

Tags: swift, xcode, package, swift-package-manager

[Here is a link to my package.](https://github.com/ElevatedUnderdogs/PackageTest2/tree/develop)

So after updating my Swift Package and its version tag,

I am getting the following errors when I try to update the package in my project that consumes the package.

```
Missing package product 'MyPackage1'
❕Package resolution errors must be fixed before building
```

```
https://github.com/ElevatedUnderdogs/PackageTest2.git
 has no Package.swift manifest for version 1.0.1
```

`1.0.0` is the original.  `1.0.1` is my updated version.

Does this mean I need to create a new Package.swift for every single version? I don't even see a place in the `Package.swift` where I can signify the current version.

Things I've tried:

- reseting the package cache in the consuming project.
- "updating to latest package versions"
- Deleting the Swift Package, and then trying to add it again. Before adding it completes, I get: "MyProject.git has no `Package.swift` manifest for version `1.0.1`.
- Package.swift is in the root directory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69793517/9440709

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the tag was updated on an incorrect remote branch which wasn't merged to yet, so the tag's corresponding commit didn't have the `Package.swift` file.  It is a good practice to check the commit hash of the version you are trying to access to verify that it has the correct code.

[image]